# Как одновременно перехватывать касания в onTouch методе и двойной клик для RelativeLayout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Как одновременно перехватывать касания в onTouch методе и двойной клик для RelativeLayout??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

### activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gradient">
</RelativeLayout>
```

### MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private GestureDetectorCompat DoubleTap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    RelativeLayout main_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

    DoubleTap = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new MyGestureListener());
    main_layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN == event.getAction()){
                Log.d("...", "onTouch сработал");
            }
            return DoubleTap.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });
}

private class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.d("...", "DoubleTap сработал");
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, Учитель  - Вам нужно памятник при жизни поставить! Обгуглился уже, много чего перепробовал, но безрезультатно (как, например, вот фишка нерабочая была: https://gyazo.com/2fe46b9499b1c1ee05fbc3a98bb68bb9  ) Андрей, спасибо огромное за ответ и поддержку...

Comment: Dmitriy Antonov спасибо за комментарий), обращайтесь.